# I can't accessing JSON data in jQuery returning from Asp.Net WebMethod

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I want to access json data into jQuery returning from Asp.Net Web Method.
This is my web Method

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public string GetChat() {
    //
    // Code to get data into dataset from database
    //

    // below code to convert dataset to json string
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row;

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
        {
            row.Add(dc.ColumnName.Trim(), dr[dc]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }

    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

Here is my jQuery Code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "../chat.asmx/GetChat",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.d[0].Name);
    },
    error: function (result) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

Here is Json Response Sample:

```
[
{
    "EmployeeId":3,
    "Name":"Khushbu Agarwal",
    "Cnt":2
},
{
    "EmployeeId":6,
    "Name":"Priyanka Jain",
    "Cnt":3
}
]
```

Now, When I access data in jQuery by statement:

```
alert(data.d[0].Name);
```

It displays `Undefined`
Can any one help me on this. I am new to json.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you run in debug, are you hitting the method? Also, use console.log and not alert, you'll get some better information using the chrome/firebug tools

Comment: Console.log method also display `undefined`. and I am already using and tracing Javascript and AJAX by Firebug Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have double JSON serialization here. Don't do plumbing in your WebMethod. Just return an object that will hold the data:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
public List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetChat() 
{
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn dc in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
        {
            row.Add(dc.ColumnName.Trim(), dr[dc]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }

    return rows;
}
```

and then inside your success callback for example if you wanted to access the first row:

```
success: function (data) {
    alert(data.d[0]);
},
```

And if you wanted to access some particular columns name of the first row:

```
alert(data.d[0]['ColumnName'].Value);
```